# recast function in reshape2 outputs a list

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I used to work with the `reshape` library and switched to `reshape2` as it is supposed to be faster.

But I obtain very strange results as outputs of the `recast` function :

- Using `reshape::recast`, I obtain a proper dataframe the way I want
  it.
- Using `reshape2::recast`, I obtain a list with labels `data` (which
  is the matrix that I would want to see as my result dataframe) and `labels` which is itself a list containing my x-axis and y-axis labels.

I know it's possible to reconstruct my dataframe the way I want it from there but can't it be done directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own function by simply adding a mere `d` to the `recast` code:

```
redcast <- function (data, formula, ..., id.var, measure.var) {
  if (any(c("id.vars", "measure.vars") %in% names(match.call()))) {
    stop("Use var, not vars\n")
  }
  molten <- melt(data, id.var, measure.var)
  dcast(molten, formula, ...)
}

redcast(french_fries, time ~ variable, id.var = 1:4)

# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#    time potato buttery grassy rancid painty
# 1     1     72      72     72     72     72
# 2     2     72      72     72     72     72
# 3     3     72      72     72     72     72
# 4     4     72      72     72     72     72
# 5     5     72      72     72     72     72
# 6     6     72      72     72     72     72
# 7     7     72      72     72     72     72
# 8     8     72      72     72     72     72
# 9     9     60      60     60     60     60
# 10   10     60      60     60     60     60
```

Comment: I agree with your solution here (+1) but do you think that this is maybe an oversight for what is possibly an under-utilized function? The only think that I can think of is that this was designed to work with both `dcast` and `acast`, hence the conversion to a list, but not sure why there isn't a function that "reassembles" the output.

Comment: I don't know. I don't see a need for this function. It only saves one line of code and "imposes [additional] cognitive burden" (to cite Hadley).

Comment: that's sort of what I mean. It doesn't seem to be well-advertised, and I can't quite figure out why it exists to begin with....

Comment: I accepted the answer because that is what I ended up doing but I still think it should be done at the original function level, if for nothing else, to be consistent with the previous behavior of the function.

Comment: Also I don't agree with the previous comments on the use case for `recast`. I very rarely use `melt` or `cast` by themselves so `recast` is a big help.